# Android Studio IDE unable to refer to classes from a library module

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 0.2.2
I've imported an existing eclipse project, which has the classic eclipse ADT project 
structure and added a gradle build script into it.
Let's name it `ProjectA`

Then I created a module in it, which has the new Android Studio structure,
And added it as library in `File>Project` Structure dialog.
Let's name it `LibA`

The problem is this - `ProjectA` is somewhy lacking the classpath of LibA and therefore the IDE's java parser fails to see classes from `LibA`, therefore I'm getting a lot of errors on
the IDE's side.

Gradle of course, compiles everything ok because the build process is no longer related to the `IDE` as it were in `Eclipse`.

Anyone got any pointers in the matter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a library, go to

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> click + then add the jar.

Once it has been added, it will ask you for the module which is dependent on jar. Select ProjectA from the list. That should link the library to Module.

Comment: Done that, the LibA project is not a jar, but sources, intellisense doesn't see any of the classes of LibA in ProjectA or from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After setup dependencies in build.gradle:

try "Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: "File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> You app project -> Dependencies" and add "Module Dependency" to ProjectA

Comment: No luck, maybe I'm missing something gradle wise? I only have the lib project declare in settings.gradle like this :include ':LibA'

Comment: You need add this: dependencies { compile project(':LibA') } to you build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Set up you configs like this:

**/settings.gradle**

```
include ':LibA', ':progect'
```

**/project/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':LibA')
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't that, it was a truely silly reason, the src directory of LibA wasn't marked as source directory, to make it a source directory, I had to right click on LibA/src/main/src and choose Mark Directory As>root sources directory

Comment: I had the same issue working with a project exported from Eclipse. You have to keep the sourceSets definitions in build.gradle and make sure they are correct across all library modules you depend on for your project.